# RabbitMQ browser-based UI unable to innest HashMap in Headers field

Tags: rabbitmq

The header of my message in RabbitMQ Queue has this specification:

```
headers={
          httpHeaders={transactionID=123, sessionID=451554}, 
          contentType=text/plain,
          timestamp=1539607167303
          }
```

so I have an embedded **Hashmap** in the key named *httpHeaders*.
I want replicate this behaviour using the RabbitMQ UI, but I do not understand how to set it

[image]

The select List options are only: String, Boolean, Number and List

This is my test that replicate programmatically the Message Header:

```
@Test
public void getTransactionId() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    String payload = "payload";
    Map messageHeader = new HashMap();
    Map httpHeader = new HashMap();
    httpHeader.put(HttpHeaderKeys.TRANSACTION_ID_KEY, "123");
    messageHeader.put(HTTP_HEADER_KEY, httpHeader);
    MessageHeaders messageHeaders = new MessageHeaders(messageHeader);
    GenericMessage message = new GenericMessage(payload, messageHeaders);
    Method method = MDCUtils.class.getDeclaredMethod("getTransactionId", Message.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    Object result = method.invoke(null, message);
    assertEquals("123", result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the headers in this way:

[image]

Comment: I receive a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect type specified for header 'headerHttp'. Expected [interface java.util.Map] but actual type is [class java.lang.String]` because _httpHeaders_ is considered a String and not a Map. The execution fails in `message.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaderKeys.HTTP_HEADER_KEY, Map.class)`  where I converted it in order to obtain the value of *transactionID* key